# Sum on Union query - syntax error - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do sum on union query and I am getting

> Syntax error: incorrect syntax near ')'

Code:

```
select 
    sum(rate) 
from 
    (select 
         sum(UnitsDelivered * Rate) as rate 
     from 
         Reimbursement_EBSUtilization 
     where 
         PRR_Id = 1 

     UNION ALL

     select 
         sum(Reimbursement_CDSUtilization.Rate * CDSUtilization.UnitsDelivered) as rate 
     from 
         Reimbursement_CDSUtilization
     left join 
         CDSUtilization on Reimbursement_CDSUtilization.CDSU_Id = CDSUtilization.Id
     where 
         Reimbursement_CDSUtilization.PRR_Id = 270
)--syntax error is showing here
```

I am sure I am missing something very small but couldn't figure out

Comment: `where Reimbursement_CDSUtilization.PRR_Id = 270
) x` You need to alias your subquery with any name.

Comment: after ')' try `as t` where t is an alias

Comment: oops i missed it. Thank you. it works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alias the subquery:

```
select sum(rate) from 
(
  select sum(UnitsDelivered*Rate) as rate 
   from Reimbursement_EBSUtilization 
   where PRR_Id =1 

   UNION ALL

  select sum(Reimbursement_CDSUtilization.Rate * CDSUtilization.UnitsDelivered) as rate 
  from Reimbursement_CDSUtilization
  left join CDSUtilization on Reimbursement_CDSUtilization.CDSU_Id = CDSUtilization.Id
  where Reimbursement_CDSUtilization.PRR_Id = 270
) as t -- <-- use alias here
```